# How to return similar xml elements as rows in oracle

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, oracle11g, xml-parsing

I am trying to parse xml in my oracle DB to return individual rows. The xml is a field called msg in my table
Sample xml is

```xml
<application  xmlns="http://www.abcxyz.com/Schema/FCX/1" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
     <client>
        <clientSource>
          <amount>25000.0</amount>
          <clientSourceTypeDd>1</clientSourceTypeDd>
          <description>aasdadsf</description>
        </clientSource>
        <clientSource>
          <amount>25000.0</amount>
          <clientSourceType>6</clientSourceTypeDd>
          <description>wrewertwerewrt</description>
        </clientSource>
        <clientSource>
          <amount>50000.0</amount>
          <clientSourceType>10</clientSourceTypeDd>
          <description>second and thirs</description>
        </clientSource>
    </client>
</application>
```

I have tried the below query but not working as expected

```sql
SELECT EXTRACT(t.msg, '//application/client/clientSource[*]/clientSourceType/text()')
       .getStringVal() clientSourceType,
       EXTRACT(t.msg, '/pplication/client/clientSource/amount')
       .getStringVal() clientSourceAmount
  FROM table t
```

The expected result I want to achieve is

| clientSourceType | clientSourceAmount |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 25000 |
| 6 | 25000 |
| 10 | 50000 |

Please help resolve as I am new to parse xml and oracle.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[`XMLTABLE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/XMLTABLE.html#GUID-C4A32C58-33E5-4CF1-A1FE-039550D3ECFA)**, which is recommended by Oracle rather than deprecated function **`EXTRACTVALUE`**, after fixing tag names by converting `clientSourceTypeDd` to `clientSourceType` in order to make opening and closing tag names match such as

```sql
WITH t( xml ) AS
(
 SELECT XMLType('<application xmlns="http://www.abcxyz.com/Schema/FCX/1" 
                     xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                     <client>
                        <clientSource>
                          <amount>25000.0</amount>
                          <clientSourceType>1</clientSourceType>
                          <description>aasdadsf</description>
                        </clientSource>
                        <clientSource>
                          <amount>25000.0</amount>
                          <clientSourceType>6</clientSourceType>
                          <description>wrewertwerewrt</description>
                        </clientSource>
                        <clientSource>
                          <amount>50000.0</amount>
                          <clientSourceType>10</clientSourceType>
                          <description>second and thirs</description>
                        </clientSource>
                    </client>
                 </application>')
   FROM dual
)
SELECT "clientSourceType", "clientSourceAmount"
  FROM t,
  XMLTABLE( XMLNAMESPACES( DEFAULT 'http://www.abcxyz.com/Schema/FCX/1' ),
            '/application/client/clientSource'
      PASSING xml
      COLUMNS 
             "clientSourceType"   INT PATH 'clientSourceType',
             "clientSourceAmount" INT PATH 'amount'
         )
```

| clientSourceType | clientSourceAmount |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 25000 |
| 6 | 25000 |
| 10 | 50000 |

**<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=da38912b7fd487b180bf44a28f60b6c4)</kbd>**

Comment: Thanks Barbaros, the xml contains namespace, how do I use it? your query is returning an empty table when I run it. Thank you

Comment: This worked so as expected, thank you once again

Comment: can you please help me with this question? Thanks
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71816984/how-to-return-values-in-xml-with-different-xpath-in-oracle